# How do you update an object in an array based on another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If you have two arrays with objects **:**

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1, goal: 'fun'}, {id: 2, goal: 'work'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, salary: '$25k'}, {id: 2, salary: '25k'}];
```

How do you update arr1 to add another property of salary `where arr1.id === arr2.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over each element of *arr1* and return a new array.
- When *arr1* traverses, you can get the current element *id*, use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
  to filter the *arr2* element, and return an element array that matches
  the current element *id*.
- Based on the fact that some people may not get a *salary*, use the
  [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to obtain the *salary* attribute.
- When returning, if the person does not get the *salary*, it will not
  change, and when the person gets the *salary*, use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax),
  copy the current element attribute, and add the *salary* attribute.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: '1', goal: 'fun'},
  {id: '2', goal: 'work'},
  {id: '3', goal: 'slacker'}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id: '1', salary: '$25k'}, 
  {id: '2', salary: '$25k'}
];

const result = arr1.map(o1 => {
  const salary = arr2.filter(o2 => o2.id === o1.id)[0]?.salary;
  return salary ? {...o1, salary} : o1;
});

result.forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**try map and filter, the code sucks but it works**

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1,name:'tom'},{id:2,name:'john'}]
const arr2 = [{id:1,apd:'tomAppend'},{id:2,apd:'johnAppend'}]
arr1.map(item=>{
   item.apd = arr2.filter(item2=>item2.id===item.id)[0].apd
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with the [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, goal: 'fun'}, {id: 2, goal: 'work'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, salary: '$25k'}, {id: 2, salary: '25k'}];

const res = arr1.map(obj => {   
    obj.salary = arr2.find(({ id }) => id === obj.id).salary;
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```