# Replacing property value in one object array if property matches from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have javascript object like this

```
var arr1 = [{name:'qqq'}, 
           {name:'www'}, 
           {name:'eee'},
           {name:'rrr'}]

var arr2 = [{value:'qqq',url:'123'}, 
           {value:'www',url:'456'}]
```

I need to replace objects in arr1 with url from arr2 with matching name and value.

So here is the result I want to get:

```
var arr1  = [{name:'123'}, 
           {name:'456'}, 
           {name:'eee'},
           {name:'rrr'}]
```

Comment: Yes I got my issue resolved..thanks to the contributors!!

Answer (score -1):

So you need to loop through arr1 and filter arr2 by name value, if you will get result, then replace name value with url value:

```
  let replacedValues = arr1.map(o1 => {
    let fResult = arr2.filter(o2 => o2.value === o1.name)[0]
    if(fResult) {
      o1.name = fResult.url
    }
    return o1
  })
```

Comment: flag as duplicate please. This looks uncannily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73075014/13762301 (also `filter()[0]` is a very poor stand-in for `find()`)

Comment: Even o1 and o2 lol :D Okay I'll flag it